# How do I export a xcode project with it's images?

Tags: xcode, xcode-project

I'm trying to export a Xcode project to my new mac, but at the time of creating the project, when added images I didn't check the "Copy to destinations folder".

So, when I open the Folder containing the project some images are missing.

[image]

Is there no other way but coping all those individual images and exporting them too? ( about 100 )

Thanks!

Comment: this link maybe helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613358/move-xcode-project-causes-red-textmissing-files-from-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all your resources into a single folder and then drag that folder into Xcode and then when the "Choose options for adding these files" sheet pops up you select the "Create folder references for any added folders" then that folder will be added by reference and whatever files are in it will be copied to your application bundle at build time. This means that you won't have to individually manage each image file… just add the ones you want to the referenced folder.
[image]