# Can't open Project in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, project

[image: Components of the project file is as follows:]

project.xcodeproj shows red color, how to resolve this issue

[image: But it does not open fully when open the project as follows :]

Comment: could you show what happens when you open .xcworkspace? Are all files there?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613358/move-xcode-project-causes-red-textmissing-files-from-project

Comment: @DCDC also open .xcworkspace file occurs same issue.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank i will see that link!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the merge conflicts in `.xcodeproject` file.

1. Click on right mouse button on file
2. Show package contents
3. Open `project.pbxproj` file in the text editor and find all places with
   merge comments
   as **@Erik Godard** commented (search for ===== to identify the conflicts)
4. Remove them
5. Restart Xcode with your project

Comment: Just a note that you can search for ===== to identify the conflicts.