# Can't open project in xcode while change location of project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have crated an app which is in desktop on my Mac Mini but now i am move project folder to another location than i can not able open project from XCode

Here is the screen shot
In This image project folder I changed location. 
[image: In This image project folder i changed location]

In this image project folder is on desktop. 
[image: In this image project folder is on desktop]

i don't know why this is happing when i move project to another location

Comment: is that your git repository?

Comment: Yes its my git repository

Comment: this is because of conflicts in `.xcodeproject` file. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781954/cant-open-project-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit file path from Xcode by selecting its Full Path from "Identity and Type" like below:

[image]